# MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: users index: mobile_1 dup key: { mobile: null }

Tags: mongoose, mobile, collections, duplicates, key

I created a user schema where I have a mobile field. The mobile field should be unique but still allow null values and should only compare uniqueness with strings. Here's my debug info:

#### The 'mobile' key inside my user schema

```
mobile: {
  type: String,
  index: {
    unique: true,
    partialFilterExpression: { mobile: { $type: 'string' } }
  },
}
```

#### mongoose debug log

```
Mongoose: users.createIndex({ mobile: 1 }, { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { mobile: { '$type': 'string' } }, background: true})
```

#### Error

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: users index: mobile_1 dup key: { mobile: null }
    at Function.create (~/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/error.js:44:12)
    at toError (~/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:150:22)
    at ~/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/common_functions.js:265:39
    at handler (~/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:971:24)
    at ~/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:496:5
    at ~/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:420:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
  driver: true,
  name: 'MongoError',
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  keyPattern: { mobile: 1 },
  keyValue: { mobile: null },
  errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: users index: mobile_1 dup key: { mobile: null }',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

I tried a lot of options and different answers from stackoverflow but nothing seems to work so I'd like ask the proper way of doing this.

**EDIT**

The issue was that the code I had was correct, but I had to delete and re-create the table for it to work. Another solution would be to just remove the indexes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue was that the code I had was correct, but I had to delete and re-create the table for it to work. Another solution would be to just remove the indexes.

Comment: Thanks , Remove old data and create new, then works fine. !!!!

Answer (score 4):

After hours of googling, I finally found the problem

The problem was I was saving to a collection that I had previously used for another application with different `userSchema` that had several unique parameters like: `phoneNumber, username` ,...

But in my current models, I had just `email` and `password` as `userSchema` and I was getting this `mongoError code 11000` with `keyPattern: { username: null }`

I just changed my `Database_Url` in my `.env` file (where I store my super secret data that don't want to hardcode in the app):

```
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myNewCollectionName
```

and restarted the node with running:

```
npm start
```

then when i tried to register a user, I didn't get that error and it solved completely.

I hope this save your day ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `sparse` index. Right now the unique index means you can only have one `user` with a null `mobile` value

From [MongoDB docs on Sparse Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/)

> Sparse indexes only contain entries for documents that have the indexed field, even if the index field contains a null value. The index skips over any document that is missing the indexed field. The index is “sparse” because it does not include all documents of a collection. By contrast, non-sparse indexes contain all documents in a collection, storing null values for those documents that do not contain the indexed field.

Here is an example of it for your code

```
users.createIndex({ mobile: 1 }, { 
  unique: true,  
  sparse: true, 
  partialFilterExpression: { mobile: { '$type': 'string' } }, 
  background: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just match the database key and value if any key does not match with your code delete the entire database then again push the data

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

as per your error, you have to delete a document with same key value pair,
you just keep one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

from myside the simple solution is just **delete(drop)** your database. probably this might resolve the issue,such issue may happens because of **redefining** of that collection's Schema.

Answer (score 0):

-Open MongoDB collection (in which you are facing the problem)
-Go to **index** tab and delete all the indexes that were showing the errors
-you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way go to your mongoDB database and click on database then click on indexes then delete some or all of the indexes, ofcourse when you are logged in .

cherrs

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I delete the database and create a new one ! then re run your application .
It will work

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the database with studio, go to appropriate collection, and find the field where duplicate error is pointing to. At the bottom, deselect Unique and Select Sparse. In case of me I was getting the same error with username field.I just did the above steps and it worked.

Note this is not recommended for fields that need to be unique(In case of mobile no) but you can do the above for fields where data is repeated such as username, likes, favorites etc.

Sometimes when a field is created through a schema, it turns it unnecessarily into unique.If you dont want it, you can change with above steps. Studio 3T makes it easy.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue i just dropped the collection and added the data again